# Using a GitHub Code in Android Project - Licensing Requirements

Tags: apache-2.0, github

I want to use a java utility class from GitHub for my android project (
https://github.com/tareknaj/BigFunctions). I saw from here [Android - External library license in project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2142/android-external-library-license-in-project) that there is no specific place to keep the license files of the utility class.

> There's no requirement of where it should be.

I understand that I can show the licenses and notices through the app. Is it required for both the license and notice to be shown. Also can I actually place the LICENSE and NOTICE files anywhere I like in my project hierarchy.